# how to find vectors that belong to 2 spans

Tags: linear-algebra

The question wants us to determine which vectors in $\mathbb R^4$ belong to both span${(1,2,-1,3),(1,-2,-1,2)}$ and span${(-1, -3, -2, -1),(1,1,0,2)}$.

My approach to this question is by finding some equations that these coordinates must satisfy to be in both spans.

I tried to do this by the following equations

- $c_1(1,2,-1,3)+c_2(1,-2,-1,2)=(a,b,c,d)$

and

- $c_3(-1,-3,-2,-1)+c_4(1,1,0,2)=(a,b,c,d) $

I tried to do elementary row operations on this but since there are 6 unknowns, I am unsure how to continue.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Sorry @DietrichBurde and José Carlos Santos, I agree that the targeted duplicate is an equivalent problem but here the question is asked in a different way. I'm not sure the asker can interpret this as an intersection of planes. Also the way the problem is approched here i very different. Am I wrong? Thanks, regards.

Answer (score -1):

Your idea is fine, but we don't need to take also $a$, $b$, $c$ and $d$ as unknowns, indeed from here

$$c_1\begin{pmatrix}1\\2\\-1\\3\end{pmatrix}+c_2\begin{pmatrix}1\\-2\\-1\\2\end{pmatrix}=c_3\begin{pmatrix}-1\\-3\\-2\\-1\end{pmatrix}+c_4\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\0\\2\end{pmatrix}$$

we can rearrange in the form $Ax=0$ and solve for $c_1$, $c_2$, $c_3$ and $c_4$ and finally find $a$, $b$, $c$ and $d$.

Comment: hi! thank you for the clarification! is it possible to explain further on how to rearrange to the form Ax=0?
when i try to solve the above equation, i get c1=c2=c3=c4=0...

Comment: This is indeed a solution, the trivial one. Now you need to check for all other solutions (that is the null space for $A$) and you can proceed by elimination.